# Export .RData into a CSV in R

Tags: r, qtlocation

I want to export fake.bc.Rdata in package "qtl" into a CSV, and when running "summary" it shows this is an object of class "cross", which makes me fail to convert it. And I tried to use resave, but there is warning :cannot coerce class ‘c("bc", "cross")’ to a data.frame.

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: Not all data can be stored in a CSV file. The data needs to have clear columns and rows.  What exactly do you want this CSV file to look like?

Comment: I want CSV showing clearly how the example data arrange, and then I know how deal with my personal data. Do you think it is possible to export 2 or more CSVs?

Comment: When you use str([your data frame name here]) what does it show?

Comment: like that:  str(fake.bc)
List of 2
$ geno :List of 19                                                                                                            $ pheno:'data.frame': 400 obs. of  4 variables:

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for comma-separated values, and is not suitable for all kinds of data.
It requires, like indicated in the comments, clear columns and rows.

Take this JSON as an example:

```
{ 
"name":"John",
 "age":30,
 "likes":"Walking","Running"
}
```

If you were to represent this in CSV-format, how would you deal with the difference in length? One way would be to have repeated data

```
name,age,likes
John,30,Walking
John,30,Running
```

But that doesn't really look right. Even if you merge the two into one you would still have trouble reading the data back, e.g.

```
name,age,likes
John,30,Walking/Running
```

Thus, CSV is best suited for [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

**TL;DR**

Can your data be represented tidily as comma-separated values, or should you be looking at alternative forms of exporting your data?

**EDIT:**

It appears you do have some options:
If you look at [the reference](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qtl/versions/1.46-2/topics/write.cross), you have the option to export your data using `write.cross()`.

For your data, you could use `write.cross(fake.bc, "csv", "myCrossData", c(1,5,13))`. It then does the following:

> Comma-delimited formats: a single csv file is created in the formats
> "csv" or "csvr". Two files are created (one for the genotype data and
> one for the phenotype data) for the formats "csvs" and "csvsr"; if
> filestem="file", the two files will be names "file_gen.csv" and
> "file_phe.csv".